# Inverse image of a subset of the codomain of a function

Tags: functions, education

I'm wondering if it's possible to evaluate the inverse image of a subset of the codomain of a function in Mathematica.

For example, if I consider $f(x) = x^2: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (for simplicity: domain $D=\mathbb{R}$, codomain $C = \mathbb{R}$) and the subset $A = [0, 25]$ of the codomain, I'd like to get the inverse image $f^{-1}(A) = \lbrace x \in D : f(x) \in A\rbrace = \lbrace x \in [0, 5] \rbrace$.

Comment: Since `FunctionDomain[{x^2, x^2 >= 0 && x^2 <= 25}, x, Reals]` produces `-5 <= x <= 5`, your guess $f^{-1}(A) = \lbrace x \in D : f(x) \in A\rbrace = \lbrace x \in [0, 5] \rbrace$ is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much @user64494

Comment: @user64494 I've a curiousity, if you write FunctionDomain[{x^2, x^2 >= -25 && x^2 <= 25}, x, Reals] which is the output? I cannot test it because I'm writing from my smartphone

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi - Since the domain is `Reals`, `x^2 >= -25 && x^2 <= 25` gives the same result as `x^2 >= 0 && x^2 <= 25`, i.e., `-5 <= x <= 5` As stated in the documentation: "If dom is Reals then all variables, parameters, constants, and function values are restricted to be real."

Comment: Hello @BobHanlon perfect!

Comment: Another approach: `Reduce[{y == x^2, 0 <= y <= 25}, {x}, {y}, Reals]`.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Hello @MichaelE2 sorry for the not well formatted question and thank you for your comments

Comment: No problem. The question has two close votes for that reason apparently, but nobody had asked you to add some code. I'm not really sure that adding `x^2` and `0 <= x^2 <= 25` really makes that much of a difference, though. :)